# how to accept double " " only with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I try accept double quotes

- match`" "` or `"welcome"`
- not match `"` or `"""`

**I use this regex** `[0-9A-Za-z "]` & try `[0-9A-Za-z "{2}]`
but match " , "" , """

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you wish to match `"welcome"` in `"welcome""`? `"abc"` and/or `"def"` in `"abc"def"`? In `"abc"""def"`?

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `"[^"]*"` which requires two quotations with 0 or more non-quotation literals between them